# How to use any field of parent class using codemodel

Tags: java, sun-codemodel

I have a class `Parent` and a class `Derived` like

```
class Parent {
    SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
}
```

Now below class i want to generate using CodeModel

```
class Derived extends Parent {
    String s = obj.invoke();
}
```

I tried below but not working

```
tryBlock.body().decl(codeModel.ref(String.class), "s", 
 (codeModel.ref(Parent.class)).staticRef("obj").invoke("invoke"));
```

How can I invoke obj rather than creating a new object as I am doing in `Parent` class?

Comment: is that Jcodemodel

Comment: yes its JCodeModel

Answer (score 1):

You could give the `Parent` class a `protected` attribute of the type `SomeClass` and use it directly in the `Derived` class:

```
public class Parent {

    protected SomeClass someObject;

    public Parent() {
        this.someObject = new SomeClass();
    }
}



public class Derived extends Parent {

    public void printInvoked() {
        System.out.println(this.someObject.invoke());
    }
}


public class SomeClass {

    public String invoke() {
        return "SomeClass invoked";
    }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in Title i have to generate the code using codeModel

Comment: I don't know *codeModel* and would have to google it... Could you provide some more information about how it works?

Comment: codeModel is used to generate source code , thats what i am trying to do the below tryBlock.body().decl(codeModel.ref(String.class), "s",
        (codeModel.ref(Parent.class)).staticRef("obj").invoke("invoke"));

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I don't have time to learn codemodel now... Generally, you need to find out how to create a structure like the one provided in this answer. I cannot help you do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the field directly using `JExpr.ref()` and use it to initialize the field:

```
    JDefinedClass derived = codeModel._class(JMod.PUBLIC, "Derived", ClassType.CLASS);
    derived._extends(Parent.class);

    derived.field(0, String.class, "s",  JExpr.ref("obj").invoke("invoke"));
```

This generates the following:

```
public class Derived
    extends Parent
{

    String s = obj.invoke();

}
```